# Android: launching Ads on click of a button

Tags: android

I have developed an android application which i have planned to launch it for free on Google Playstore. However, for income purpose, i have embedded AdMob in my app. According to what i have researched, the developer gets paid only on click of the Ads.

What i want to do is, when the user presses the exit button of my app, i would like to launch some Ads/Ad from the AdMob, just before closing my app.

Inorder to achieve this i have the following code:

```
Button exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exitButton);
exitButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            /*Some code here that would launch an AD*/

            MyActivity.this.finish(); //To exit from the app
        }
    });
```

The code for displaying an Ad inside an AdView of a layout is:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdUnitID);
layout.addView(adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR); //this is just for testing on emulator
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Is there a way to launch the contents of the Ads on exit button pressed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: display a dialog and display the add inside the dialog.

Comment: @Raghunandan: G8 Idea thanks for that. But again chances of user clicking on the Ad is lesser. I need to do something that would make sure that the Ad is clicked.

Comment: don't dismiss the dialog untill user clicks the add

Comment: @Raghunandan: Yes this is also a good idea. But the thing i just got to know is: admob bans forcing the user to click on the ad. So what i want to do is, it should not look like a forceful thing. He clicks a button launch the ad and exit from the APP. And idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want an interstitial ad, those full screen ads that appears in the apps. What you're requesting is a small banner which should appear in every activity, not just at the end.

Info on interstitials:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced

Also, forcing the user to click is banned by admob and probably you will get your account banned (your rate will be way too high and someone will check it)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info especially the Banning of account thing. +1 for the efforts. I'll accept your answer soon.

Comment: Any other approach according to u, which might seem that the click of the Ad looks accidental?

Comment: You should make the ad to be shown a lot of times. Admob controls the times the ad have been shown and the times the ad have been clicked. If the ad is clicked 100% of times it has been shown is obviously manipulated. I think 1-5% of the impressions should be clicks, more could be checked by some admob moderator

Answer (score 1):

In activity onbackpressed or in your exit button onclicklistener code, load the interestial ad and finish() the activity.

```
 public class InterstitialsAdsExampleActivity extends Activity implements
    AdListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private InterstitialAd interstitialAds = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.interstitialAds = new InterstitialAd(this, "Your ad unit id");
    this.interstitialAds.setAdListener(this);

}



public void onBackPressed() {
    AdRequest adr = new AdRequest();

    interstitialAds.loadAd(adr);

    finish();
};

@Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, ErrorCode error) {
    String message = "Load Ads Failed: (" + error + ")";

}

@Override
public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * Called when an Activity is created in front of the app (e.g. an
 * interstitial is shown, or an ad is clicked and launches a new Activity).
 */
@Override
public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
    if (interstitialAds.isReady()) {
        interstitialAds.show();
    } else {
        //Interstitial ad was not ready to be shown;
    }
}
```

}